# Postgres running in docker-compose unable to write data to mounted volume

Tags: postgresql, bash, docker, docker-compose

**Description**

I am running a Postgres container in docker-compose. I am mounting the `/data` directory needed by Postgres into the container using a volume in the `docker-compose.yml` below.

*Qualifications*

1. The Postgres user must be called `graph-node` and create a database called `graph-node`
2. I delete the `data/postgres/` folder before each `docker-compose up` using the `boot.sh` script below for application-specific reasons. Just know that `/data/postgres` is re-created on each run of `docker-compose up`.

**Expected Behavior**
Postgres boots and writes all files it needs to the mounted `/data/postgres` volume.

**Actual Behavior**
Postgres boots fine, but writes nothing to the volume.

**Possible Reasons**

This feels like a read/write permissions problem? I've added `:rw` in the third column of the volume as suggested, still no cigar. I run `chmod -R a+rwx ./data` on the data dir to get access to all files recursively .

The oddest thing to is that if I manually run `chmod -R a+rwx ./data` after booting, Postgres suddenly IS able to write to the directory all needed files. But if I run this before it's created as seen below (recursively for all things in `/data`) it does not work.

**Files**

boot.sh

```sh
# Check for data/ dir. If found, make it recursively rwx for all users. Otherwise, create it and make it recursively rwx for all users.

if [ -d "./data" ]
then
    chmod -R a+rwx ./data
else
    mkdir data
    chmod -R a+rwx ./data
fi

if [ -d "./data/postgres" ]
then
    rm -rf data/postgres
else
    echo "No data/postgres dir found. Proceeding"
fi

docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up
```

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    command:
      [
        "postgres",
        "-cshared_preload_libraries=pg_stat_statements"
      ]
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: graph-node
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: let-me-in
      POSTGRES_DB: graph-node
    volumes:
      - ./data/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
```

**Machine + Software Specs**

*Operating System:* Windows 10, WSL2, Ubuntu

*Docker Version:* 20.10.7 (running directly on the machine since it's Ubuntu, NOT in Docker Desktop like on a Mac)

Answer (score 0):

Well, not exactly an answer, but because I only needed one-run ephemeral storage for Postgres (I was deleting the data/ dir between runs anyways) I solved the problem by just removing the external volume and letting Postgres write data into the container itself, where it surely had privileges.